# Logging inside scala Option[T] call chain

Tags: scala, option-type

```
case class SomeObject(value: Int)
val start : List[Int] = List(1,2,3,5,6)

def findfour(start : List[Int]) : Option[SomeObject] = {
  start.find(_ equals 4)
    //.isNone(logger.info("Couldnt find a four!")).  <---  native way to do this?
    .map(SomeObject(_))
}
```

I have an existing call chain (more robust than the example but same scenario),
 i'd like to add a call inside the call chain to log if the Option[Int] i'm working on is None and be able to continue the call chain after that.
 Does scala have a native support for this?

Comment: So you want to instantiate `SomeObject` for the first `4` found and log the error if no `4` found. If that's the case then `fold()` should do it for you.

Comment: Can you give a short example on how fold will be used in this case?

Comment: `find(_ == 4).fold{logger.info(...);Option.empty[SomeObject]}(x =>Some(SomeObject(x)))`

Answer (score 3):

There is no native way. You probably can use some library but you can also write such extension method by yourself i.e.

```
implicit class OrNone[A](fa: Option[A]) {
  def isNone(log: => Unit): Option[A] = {
    if (fa.isEmpty) log
    fa
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways (if not more) to go about it.

I like the `fold()` method, but you have to re-wrap the `Option`.

```
def findfour(start : List[Int]) : Option[SomeObject] =
  start.find(_ equals 4)
       .fold{logger.info(...)
             Option.empty[SomeObject] //re-create the None
       }(x =>Some(SomeObject(x)))
```

Alternately, if you're on Scala 2.13.x, then the new chaining methods might be a bit cleaner and clearer.

```
import scala.util.chaining._

def findfour(start : List[Int]) : Option[SomeObject] =
  start.find(_ equals 4)
       .tap(x => if (x.isEmpty) logger.info(...))
       .map(SomeObject)
```